# Avoid untrusted variables in DML query

Tags: query

```java
public static void isOdesevaUser(){
    String query = 'Select Banker_Role__c from User where id =  '+'\''+UserInfo.getUserId()+'\'';
    List<User> uList = Database.query (query);
    if(uList != null && uList.size() > 0){
        String bankerRole = String.valueOf(uList[0].get('Banker_Role__c'));
        if(String.isNotBlank(bankerRole) && bankerRole.equalsIgnoreCase('bypass')){
            isCurrentUserOdesevaUser = true;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: How to avoid apex injection?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. A simple title and a code dump isn't enough information. You need to [edit] your question to include more details here so that other people can understand the problem you're facing.

Comment: Some general notes on the code you've provided: You don't need to use a dynamic query here (that is, using `database.query()`), and you're probably better off using a normal (static) query. Also, a query will _never_ return null, so you do not need to perform a null check on `uList`.

Comment: can you give me some more idea with example

Comment: Take a look at this in Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/secure-serverside-development/mitigate-soql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your dynamic query with a static one:

```
public static void isOdesevaUser(){
    List<User> uList = [Select Banker_Role__c from User where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    if(uList.size() > 0){
        String bankerRole = String.valueOf(uList[0].Banker_Role__c));
        if(String.isNotBlank(bankerRole) && bankerRole.equalsIgnoreCase('bypass')){
            isCurrentUserOdesevaUser = true;
        }            
    }
}
```